# checking for convergence (TIFR GS $2010$)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Question is to check for convergence of sequence $(x_n)$ defined as  :

$x_1=0.1,x_2=0.101,x_3=0.101001$,.......

What i have done so far is :

I could not guess what would be $x_4$ but tried to write $x_1,x_2,x_3$ in simple way (I guess it is simple)

$$0.1= \frac{1}{10}$$

$$ 0.101=\frac{101}{1000}=\frac{100}{1000}+\frac{1}{1000}=\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{1000}$$

$$0.101001=\frac{101001}{1000000}=\frac{101000}{1000000}+\frac{1}{1000000}=\frac{101}{1000}+\frac{1}{1000000}=\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{1000}+\frac{1}{1000000}=\frac{1}{10}+(\frac{1}{10})^3+(\frac{1}{10})^6$$

So, I guess $4^{th}$ term should be something like

$$x_4=\frac{1}{10}+(\frac{1}{10})^3+(\frac{1}{10})^6+(\frac{1}{10})^9$$

forgetting about first term i guess rest would be infinite geometric sum

$$\frac{1}{10}+\sum \big(\frac{1}{10}\big)^{3i}=\frac{1}{10}+\frac{\frac{1}{10^3}}{1-(\frac{1}{10})^3}=\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{999}=\frac{1009}{9990}$$

I would be thankful if someone can assure If my guess reasonable and correct?

Answer (score 1):

This seems correct to me, however you should add the indices to the sum to make clear that
$$S = \frac1{10} + \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac1{1000^i} = \frac{1009}{9990}$$
Since the geometric series usually starts with $i=0$ and gives $\frac{1}{1- \alpha}$ as a limit.

---

Not that for the proof of convergence it would be easier to see that $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence, since
$$|x_n - x_m| \leq \frac2{10^{3\min(n,m)}} \to 0 \qquad (n,m) \to\infty$$